# Converting HashMap key values to Char Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following HashMap that I insert character-int pairs in a method and return this hashmap:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (...) {
    hmap.put(string[i], number[i]); 
}
```

However, when I want to convert this returned hashmap keys to char array, it includes also brackets and commas:

```
char[] charArray = myReturnedHashMap.keySet().toString().toCharArray(); 
//it returns 8 char "[ A , B , C , ]" instead of just "A B C"
```

So, how can I fix it?

***Update:*** On the other hand, I am not sure if HashMap is a good idea to use in this scenario. I have a loop and I just need to return char and int value pairs. Then in the other method I convert char values to a chararray. Any idea?

Comment: @am0awad I think you did not see the comment line *it returns 8 char "[ A , B , C , ]" instead of just "A B C"*.

Comment: It's because you're converting keys into a string representation which adds , and [ ] for pretty output and then doing `.toCharArray()` on top of the pretty output. What you need to do is iterate on the `keySet()` and put them in a char array

Comment: Has any Java Developer got any idea? :(

Comment: @sonnet Is there any iteration via lambda expression e.g. map(m=>m....)? Any example pls?

Comment: don't use the `toString` method for conversion Instead use the `toArray()` method on the Set returned by `myReturnedHashMap.keySet()` (Note that this will give you a `Character[]` but if you want/need to convert that to a `char[]` I'm sure you can find some solution already here on SO.

Comment: @am0awad Not printing, converting. I need to get each character value and then convert them to chararray without brackets, commas. Are you sure that you read the question?

Comment: @sonnet Told you. The toString() adds the brackets to make it look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy, very resuable (works with all kind of maps) and easily sortable solution:

```
char[] charArray = map.keySet().stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Here's the fastest solution:

```
char[] chars = new char[map.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Character c : map.keySet()) {
    chars[i++] = c;
}
```

The keys in a HashMap aren't sorted. Use [another map implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or [sort the stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: Seems very smart solution, but unfortunately "The method collect(Collector<? super Character,A,R>) in the type Stream<Character> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,String>)" error thrown. Any idea?

Comment: @hexadecimal Sorry, I had a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Doesn't this create a lot of unnecessary strings? I'd just use a for-each loop to loop through the key set (assuming order doesn't matter).

Comment: @Sweeper It's one solution, that works for all kind of Maps, allows sorting and produces the desired `char[]` instead of `Character[]`.

Comment: @steffen Dear Steffen, I encountered sorting error that you warned. The order of the elements are changed and for this reason I need to sort items. I look at the link, but could not sort. Could you also post the sorting example to your answer. I see that it is serious issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @hexadecimal Yes, that's why I first came up with that solution. What do you mean by "I couldn't"? How do you want your elements be sorted / in which order do you want to process the keys?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the call of 'keySet().toString()' - this creates the string representation of the map.

I think you want something like this:

```
Map<Character, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
hmap.put('c', 1);
hmap.put('d', 2);
hmap.put('e', 3);

Character[] charArray = hmap.keySet().toArray(new Character[0]);
```

Edit: If you need the keys sorted, you can use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap. But be aware, if you are dealing with characters and expecting language specific sorting you need a Collator for sorting in the TreeMap.

Comment: That produces `Character[]` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @steffen Yes, but I get the result correctly, Is there any problem with this implementation?

Comment: @TomStroemer Sorry, but it returns exception. Any idea?

Comment: @hexadecimal No, the solution is fine, as long as the order doesn't matter and your code works with both `char[]` and `Character[]`!

Comment: @hexadecimal what exception do you get?

Comment: @TomStroemer I fixed now, not related to the code you post. Thanks.

Comment: @steffen Thanks for informing. But in this case, regarding to the order issue, value-key pairs cannot mixed you mean? For example, for these value key pairs, <A, 1>, <B,2>, <C,3> could be <B,2>,<A, 1>, <C,3> but not <B,1>,<A, 3>, <C,2>. Is that true?

Comment: @hexadecimal yes, that is true. HashMap does not guarantee any order for its keys but of course it will never mix up the key-value mapping (otherwise the whole class would be useless).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toArray()` with the caveat that it'll return an `Object[]` array.

```
Object[] charArray = myReturnedHashMap.keySet().toArray();
```

test demo from jshell:

```
jshell> HashMap<Character, Integer> a = new HashMap<>()
a ==> {}

jshell> a.put('a', 1)
$11 ==> null

jshell> a.keySet()
$12 ==> [a]

jshell> a.keySet().to
toArray(     toString()   

jshell> a.keySet().toArray()
$13 ==> Object[1] { 'a' }

jshell> a.keySet().toArray()[0]
$14 ==> 'a'

jshell> (char)a.keySet().toArray()[0]
$15 ==> 'a'
```

Comment: I already tried it but throws error when getting char value like `(char) charArray[0]`.

Comment: what error is it. i tried this and mine seemed to work fine.

Comment: i've updated the demo from my jshell to demo that the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` in unnecessary in your case. You just want to take that `Set` and convert it to an Array. Something like this seems to work just fine:

```
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    hmap.put('a',1);
    hmap.put('b',1);
    hmap.put('c',1);
    Set<Character> characters = hmap.keySet();
    Character[] chars = new Character[characters.size()];
    characters.toArray(chars);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

Comment: @am0awad the array contains only 3 elements, I'm just printing it to show them.

Answer (score 0):

use `toArray()`

```
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        map.put('a', 1);
        map.put('b', 1);
        Character[] charArray = map.keySet().toArray(Character[]::new);
```